# Xcode code signing and bundle ID errors and warnings

Tags: xcode

I am copying this because I originally posted this at 7 o'clock Singapore time which is 4 in the morning in the US. I recieved no answers so I'm desperate

: error: CFBundleIdentifier '5SXUF33BX9.com.rohan.fart ' contains illegal character ' '

: invalid bundle identifier '5SXUF33BX9.com.rohan.fart '

warning: Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure Farticus is a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned. (-19050) /Users/rohankapur/Documents/Fart /build/Release-iphoneos/Farticus.app/Farticus: code object is not signed - (null)

1) The illegal characters: I checked the info.plist and there are no ''. I did delete all my certificates and re-dowloaded them, and ERRORS start happening.

The warning nable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure Farticus is a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned. (-19050) /Users/rohankapur/Documents/Fart /build/Release-iphoneos/Farticus.app/Farticus: code object is not signed - (null)

this warning is new but the other warning is old. In keychain access I have my new certificates though. HELP PLEASE!

Comment: i think there is a whitespace at the end of your 'fart' word in your CFBundleIdentifier

Comment: My 'fart' words are usually followed by a brownspace. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you genererated your private keys correctly. Also, its worth pointing out that Apple has stated they will no longer be accepting fart apps into the appstore.
http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2010/09/09/apples-review-guidelines-we-dont-need-any-more-fart-apps/

Comment: Oh man isn't that a bummer, although it is a very reasonable decision